# How to drag a div up and down to scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

Instead of having a scroll bar, I want to be able to drag the div to scroll down.
The div is a bar which contains the profile pictures of users online. 
So far, I was only able to drag only one of the profile pictures. I want to be able to drag either the profile pictures ( all at once ) or drag the div to scroll when it overflows.

P.S I only want vertical scrolling and both jquery or javascript is fine with me

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for you :http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/
jQuery.kinetic is a simple plugin which adds smooth drag scrolling

Comment: did that answered your question ?